# SoapObject Result returns anyType{} as value when retuning a complexType object

Tags: android, android-ksoap2

I am calling a web service in my android app & the method is getGramaNiladhariData(),
I am getting the result as a SoapObject.

```
result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;  Log.d("WS", String.valueOf(result));
```

And this is what I got for  **String.valueOf(result)**

#### getGramaNiladhariDataResponse{getGramaNiladhariDataResult=anyType{gnName=anyType{}; address=anyType{}; workingDays=anyType{}; gnDivision=anyType{}; contactNumber=anyType{}; }; }

Here the method i am calling returns a complexType object,consist of 5 attributes.
As i found in the internet i can't get a soap Object as the result of a webservice method which return a complexType object.If so,how should i get the values.

What I want to solve is why i am getting anyType{}, as the value  ,instead of the real value.
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: erandi,
did u sorted this issue.?i tried in several ways & still in same position

Comment: in database your cell is empty so you get anyType{} , if it null the column will not be available in soap string  , anyway when you loop in column as answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50201493/6998825) you can set for ex. if(table.getProperty("ID").toString().equals("anyType{}")){ x = "" }else{x=table.getProperty("ID").toString()} , otherwise if column not in result string so it will be nulled in database cell and it my crash your webservice request used and u will be need to hundel it with this if(table.hasProperty("ID")){x=table.getProperty("ID").toString()}else{x=""}

Answer (score 6):

Its too late to answer. but FYI and others who find this useful,

By Doing `String.valueOf(result)` you are printing the whole content of the body. but in order to get your values using parameters, first of all you need to hit in to correct `SoapObject`.

I don't know if there is any easy way to find correct `SoapObject`, but still this way do the trick, and once you get the correct `SoapObject` then you are done. find below how to find the correct `SoapObject`,

First you need to check the count of params in your very first `SoapObject`,

```
result.getPropertyCount();
```

you will get less amount of count for this since this is the very first cover,

then, Print and see which param gives you the corect details,

```
result.getProperty(0);
result.getProperty(1);
etc ...
```

Once you found the correct parameter, then grab that `SoapObject`. like this,

```
SoapObject result2 = (SoapObject) result.getProperty(0);
```

then check for the count of this object. and do the same as above until you get the correct `SoapObject`.

Once you found the last `SoapObject` it will print like this without useless strings,

```
anyType{gnName = Prasad; address = Address of the person; ; workingDays = 5; gnDivision = California; contactNumber = 0123456789}
```

Now you can go ahead with this object like this,

```
SoapObject result3 = (SoapObject) result2.getProperty(5);
Log.v("Name : ", result3.getProperty("gnName").toString());
```

And you will get the output in DDMS like below,

```
Name : Prasad
```

I guess this will help you, let me know if you have any further issues.

Answer (score 2):

anytype{} comes when you get a null value from the web service.Insert some data first and then try to fetch data from web service.

Answer (score 2):

i make own code i just finished it now i would like to share it with u may it help some

i was work with only one table and that was work with me
and i will try to explain steps

```
    try {
        // Invole web service
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION + "mywebservicecall", envelope);
        // Get the response

        SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
          //resultsString looks like this ==> anyType{schema=anyType{element=anyType{complexType=anyType{choice=anyT....etc
          //here i found some complex in getproperty(0) so i not need it
          //then i make Object1 that contain datatable from my database getproperty(1)


        SoapObject Object1 = (SoapObject) resultsString.getProperty(1);
           //object1 look like this ==> anyType{NewDataSet=anyType{Table1=anyType{ID_CAT=1; CAT_V_N=ma 
           //here my table1 i wanna to fitch the NewDataSet

        SoapObject tables = (SoapObject) Object1.getProperty(0);  //NewDataset
           //tables object now looks like this  ==> anyType{Table1=anyType{ID_CAT=1;CAT_N ...etc

           //now i wanna loop in my table to get columns valus it will be tablesObject properties depend on iteration to get row by row
        for (int i = 0; i < tables.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            SoapObject Objecttable = (SoapObject) tables.getProperty(i); 
           System.out.println("ID_CAT = " + Objecttable.getProperty("ID_CAT").toString());
           System.out.println("CAT_N= " +Objecttable.getProperty("CAT_N").toString()); 
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace(); 
           System.out.println("ID_CAT = 0 ");
           System.out.println("CAT_N = None");
    }
```

last code explain one table

now what i was just end is how to control multi tables

i will explain it also

```
        SoapObject resultsString = (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse(); 
        // the same
        SoapObject Object1 = (SoapObject) resultsString.getProperty(1); 
        // the same
        SoapObject tables = (SoapObject) Object1.getProperty(0); 
        // the same


        // the same
        for(int i = 0; i < tables.getPropertyCount(); i++){
            SoapObject Objecttable = (SoapObject) (SoapObject) tables.getProperty(i);

            try{ 

//tables.toString().substring(8,tables.toString().indexOf("=")).equals("Table1")
   // here i was try to get the name of the table to hundel it but i fount my table name in attribute id 
   // it not came as table name like if my table that comming from database is hi
   //the first row will be attrib=>id=>hi1 and sec row will be hi2 
   //the first row will be attrib=>rowOrder=>0 and sec row will be 1 
                    if(Objecttable.getAttribute("id").equals("Table1"+(Integer.valueOf(Objecttable.getAttribute("rowOrder").toString())+1))){
// so Objecttable.getAttribute("id") will be ( "Table11" ) in first row
//Objecttable.getAttribute("rowOrder").toString() ==> will be 0

//Integer.valueOf(Objecttable.getAttribute("rowOrder").toString())+1) well be 1 for first row of this table

// so Objecttable.getAttribute("id").equals("Table1"+(Integer.valueOf(Objecttable.getAttribute("rowOrder").toString())+1)) will be true 
/**
then i can loop and fitch data like single table 
*/
                }

                if(Objecttable.getAttribute("id").equals("Table2"+(Integer.valueOf(Objecttable.getAttribute("rowOrder").toString())+1))){

                }
            }catch (Exception e) {
            }
```

hope it's clear for you guys good luck

Answer (score -1):

I've had this problem before. And I solved it. I've had this problem before. And I solved it. I seemed to spend a lot of time to find a solution to this problem. My Project it's work. I create Web Service .Net  Object Array. I hope this will help you.

```
        //.................................
        SoapObject requestx = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelopex = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelopex.dotNet = true;
        envelopex.setOutputSoapObject(requestx);
        HttpTransportSE httpTransportx = new HttpTransportSE(URL);          

        try  {                    
            httpTransportx.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelopex);
            SoapObject responsex = (SoapObject)envelopex.getResponse(); // not envelopex.bodyIn;

             int i=0;
             int RCount=responsex.getPropertyCount();
             int[] tbIDArray = new int[RCount+1];
             int[] iMonthAarray = new int[RCount+1];
             int[] iYearAarray = new int[RCount+1];
             String[] sDetailAarray = new String[RCount+1];

             for (i = 0; i < RCount; i++) {
                 Object property = responsex.getProperty(i);
                 if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
                     SoapObject info = (SoapObject) property;
                     String tbID = info.getProperty("tbID").toString();
                     String iMonth = info.getProperty("iMonth").toString();
                     String iYear = info.getProperty("iYear").toString();
                     String sDetail = info.getProperty("sDetail").toString();

                    tbIDArray[i] =Integer.valueOf(tbID);
                    iMonthAarray[i] =Integer.valueOf(iMonth);
                    iYearAarray[i] =Integer.valueOf(iYear);
                    sDetailAarray[i] =sDetail;
                 }//if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
             }//for (i = 0; i < RCount; i++) {


        }  catch (Exception exception)   {
            MsgBox1(exception.toString() , "Error");
        }
```