# Call Soap Service from android

Tags: android, ksoap2

I never seen this kind of error , when I send request I received this message:

> anyType{SendResultCode=Unsuccessfull; Error=Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: address; }

I don't have any address parameter.

Here is code from java

```
                        String methodName = "SendMail";
                        String namespace = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.ge";
                        String soapAction = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.ge/SendMail";
                        String url = "http:///xx.xxx.xx.xxx/SmsService/SmsSendingService.asmx";

                        SoapObject soapObject = new SoapObject(namespace, methodName);
                        soapObject.addProperty("from","someaddress");
                        soapObject.addProperty("to","someaddress");
                        soapObject.addProperty("cc","someaddress");
                        soapObject.addProperty("bcc","someaddress");
                        soapObject.addProperty("subject","Message From App");
                        soapObject.addProperty("replyTo","someaddress");
                        soapObject.addProperty("messageBody","Some text here");
                        soapObject.addProperty("isFormatHtml",true);
                        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11); 
                        envelope.dotNet = true;
                        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(soapObject); 
                        HttpTransportSE conn = new HttpTransportSE(url);
                        conn.call(soapAction, envelope); //send request
                        SoapObject result=(SoapObject)envelope.getResponse();
```

**UPDATE**

I found my problem, it was little tricky,

> String soapAction = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.ge/SendMail"

this URL need '/' at the end like this:

> String soapAction = "http://www.xxxxxxxx.ge/SendMail/"

So now everything works fine.

Comment: maybe the webservice has changed and there is a new parameter address, which is not sent by your code

Comment: web service is working when I call it from php

Comment: check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337137/soapobject-result-returns-anytype-as-value-when-retuning-a-complextype-object

Comment: I saw that post, it's not what I need

Comment: but it is internal error returned by server.

Answer (score 1):

You did not add the Address parameter in SoapObject

```
  soapObject.addProperty("address","#fdfdsf asdasd asdasds");
```

Comment: no service don't have address parameter, I've updated my question, I found out my problem, see if you interested.